# Confusion with recursion and property setters in Python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a Binary Search Tree class. I have two classes; `BSTNode`, and `BST`. I try to enforce the search tree property in the setters for `left` and `right`:

```
class BSTNode(object):


    def __init__(self,new):
        if type(new) is BSTNode:
            self._data = new.data
        else:
            self._data = new
        self._left = None
        self._right = None


    @property
    def data(self):
         return self._data


    @property
    def left(self):
        return self._left


   @left.setter
   def left(self,data):
        if data is None:
            self._left = None
        else:
            n = BSTNode(data)
            if n.data >= self.data:
                del n
                raise ValueError("Value must be less-than parent!")
            self._left = n


    @property
    def right(self):
        return self._right


    @right.setter
    def right(self,data):
        if data is None:
            self._right = None
        else:
            n = BSTNode(data)
            if n.data < self.data:
                del n
                raise ValueError("Value must be greater-than or equal-to parent!")
            self._right = n


class BST(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None


    @property
    def root(self):
        return self._root


    @root.setter
    def root(self,value):
        self._root = BSTNode(value)


    def binary_insert(self,list_in):
        self.root = binary_insert(list_in,0,len(list_in) - 1)
```

Now, I am trying to implement a method `binary_insert(self,list_in)` where I insert a sorted list into the tree such that the tree is balanced (using essentially binary search); however, my left and right nodes off of `root` are always `None`, though I assign them explicitly in the function, and I am sure my indices are correct, as I get the following to print when I run it:

```
> t = BST()
> list_in = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
> t.binary_insert(list_in)
4
1
0
2
3
6
5
7
8
```

Here is my function (note instance method `binary_insert` above in class `BST`):

```
def binary_insert(list_in,imin,imax):
    if imax < imin:
        return None
    imid = int(floor((imax + imin) / 2))
    n = BSTNode(list_in[imid])
    print(n.data)
    n.left = binary_insert(list_in,imin,imid-1)
    n.right = binary_insert(list_in,imid+1,imax)
    return n
```

I am always returning a `BSTNode`, which is `None` only when the input to the setter is `None`, though the only node in the tree after the function runs is `root`. I suspect there is something going on with the properties that I don't understand. I'd love some clarification on this.

```
 > t = BST()
 > list_in = [0,5,12]
 > t.binary_insert(list_in)
 5
 0
 12
 > t.root.data 
 5
 > t.root.left
 None
 > t.root.right
 None
```

Expected:

```
 > t.root.left.data
 0
 > t.root.right.data
 12
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual question is?  What part of the output is what you're not expecting, and what do you expect it to be instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs because the following line executes after all the recursion is done and root is created as a BSTNode -

```
self.root = binary_insert(list_in,0,len(list_in) - 1)
```

That is at the end `binary_insert()` returns a `BSTNode` which is the root, this calls the `setter` for `root` , which is -

```
@root.setter
def root(self,value):
    self._root = BSTNode(value)
```

This causes `self._root` to be initialized with a new `BSTNode` reference whose data is same as that of root returned from `binary_insert()` , this calls the `__init__()` for `BSTNode` passing in the `root` as the argument. And the `__init__()` function of `BSTNode` does this -

```
def __init__(self,new):
    if type(new) is BSTNode:
        self._data = new.data
    else:
        self._data = new
    self._left = None
    self._right = None
```

Here , you are setting `self._left` to `None` and `self._right` to `None` . So the root's left and right values are none, as you observed.

Two ways you can solve this issue, one is -

change the line where you are setting `self.root` to -

```
def binary_insert(self,list_in):
    self._root = binary_insert(list_in,0,len(list_in) - 1)
```

---

Or you can also, change the `__init__()` BSTNode , such that if the `type(new)` is `BSTNode` , you copy over the `left` and `right` values from the `new` `BSTNode` as well. Example -

```
def __init__(self,new):
    if type(new) is BSTNode:
        self._data = new.data
        self._left = new.left
        self._right = new.right
    else:
        self._data = new
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
```

Comment: Well now it seems obvious! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your insert method is building a tree, but it's not attaching to the root and all references to the tree are being lost.

By the way, note that your method for balancing the tree (choosing the middle of the partition of the list) only works if the list is sorted. You'll need to either sort the list beforehand or use a more general balancing scheme like an AVL tree or a Red-Black tree